# Парсинг .onion доменов

Tags: tor

Добрый день, можете подсказать где/как спарсить .onion домены? Возможно есть какой нибудь аналог eschalot, но только для генерации рандомных, существующих доменов? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Вопросы по теме, которые тем не менее не стоит задавать: ... Вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию.*

Comment: Можно переформулировать так... есть ли алгоритм, по которому я могу генерировать рандомные .onion адреса?